# How to check if admin privileges are needed to access a folder even if already has admin?

Tags: python, windows

I need a way to be able to check/test if admin privileges are need to access a folder in python. The one difference that is making me make whole new question about this is that the method should work even if the program has admin privileges.

In theory a function like this should be able to check if admin is required.

```py
import os


def check_admin(path):
    """Returns `True` if admin privileges are required to access `path` and `False` if otherwise"""
    try:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(path, "dkfjsdlfjsdkl"))
    except PermissionError:
        return True
    else:
        os.rmdir(os.path.join(path, "dkfjsdlfjsdkl"))
        return False
```

And sure enough, doing `check_admin(r'C:\Windows')` will return `True`. So why am I asking this? Well, if you take that same program and run it as an admin, then `check_admin(r'C:\Windows')` returns `False` which is **not** what I want.

I have looked all over SO and none of the answers match the requirenments. Even `os.access` doesn't really do what I want (`os.access(r"C:\Windows", os.X_OK)` returns `True`).

So again, I need a way to be able to check/test if admin privileges are need to access a folder in python.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that it works on Windows OS, but in Ubuntu you can try something like this:

```
import pathlib
pathlib.Path("/usr").owner()
pathlib.Path("/usr").group()

>> 'root'
>> 'root'
```